# Handling voids in SRTM3 data

Tags: srtm, void

When I actually work with SRTM 3 data in a meteorological application and especially when doing simulation over mountainous regions I expected and found a lot of voids in SRTM3 data. Has there been anyone here who has actually fixed the voids by interpolating using bilinear interpolation as this developer has done - http://fossies.org/dox/gpsprune_17.1_source/LookupSrtmFunction_8java_source.html and then can talk about their experiences with the "fixed" SRTM 3 data ?

Or the better option is to download the NASA void filled SRTM 3 data. I do not want to go down the route of using ASTER GDEMs for various reasons.

Comment: Isn't the easiest option to download NASA's SRTM v3 data? Why would you want to go down the difficult path of implementing void-filling yourself when NASA has already done the job (and probably better than something you could do)?

Comment: @Igor - I agree downloading would be best. But I was just asking for user experiences in this field especially in regards to mountainous regions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a SRTM v4 version with gaps filled using the method described in Reuter et al (2007). It is availalbe on the [cgiar](http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org) Website. Note that users are  prohibited from  any commercial,  non-free resale,  or redistribution without explicit written permission from CIAT.

Personnally I've found that the version from [Jonathan de Ferranti](http://www.viewfinderpanoramas.org/dem3.html) was slightly better (only tested in Europe) because it is filled and corrected with ancillary data. But there is no published method.

> Reuter  H.I,  A.  Nelson,  A.  Jarvis,  2007,  An  evaluation  of 
>   void  filling interpolation  methods  for  SRTM  data,  International 
>   Journal  of  Geographic Information Science, 21:9, 983-1008.

Comment: SRTM v4 (from cgiar) = licence due to processing can affect you (so depending on your use case, not a good idea) http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/SELECTION/SRT_disclaimer.htm. See also http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/SRTM

Comment: I've mentioned CGIAR because their method is documented and published, but as I said and used the seond dataset (not because of the licence because it was for reserch, but because the mountain areas were better). Antway, you are right that I should heve mentioned the licence, so I've updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

Using the data on http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/SRTM/SRTMGL3.003/2000.02.11/ seems like a good option.  Does anyone know if this site will be maintained?